# Concept of verifying U-boot image from kernel booting

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot

If you know u-boot verified boot, it will easy to understand my idea and question. You may read from here - 
http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/uImage.FIT/verified-boot.txt;h=e639e7ae71a1e6bbe0f421630959369ec15fcf3a;hb=HEAD

In verified boot scenario, u-boot read and compare the kernel and other (e.g. dtb) binary's hash value and allow those binary to execute, if hash value matched (through FIT image). But, if you can replace the u-boot binary with the one that is not implemented with verified boot functionality, you can overcome the hash value checking facility and able to boot the same kernel image.

So, my idea is - whether is it possible to check the u-boot image from kernel while booting?

I was reading, that reading a file from from kernel is a bad idea and risky. But I also read that using /proc or other feature it is possible to have IO operations from kernel space.

Would like to have an expert suggestion, whether my idea of verifying u-boot from kernel may possible? And, if yes - some guideline.

Thanks.

Comment: It may be possible but it would be useless. You don't trust the kernel to run, yet you trust it to check u-boot? The idea is to burn the bootloader in a really RO memory and make it load only signed images. Just like Apple do with iPhones (though they have more stages).

Comment: Trust of kernel would be done by u-boot [as verified booting doing it]. Unfortunately loading signed image from bootloader also fall in same situation, if the bootloader is possible to replace.
I just want to bind the bootloader and kernel together, either use both or none. thanks.

Comment: If somebody can replace your bootload then the kernel can be tempered to skip the bootloader verification. If you don't control the bootloader you don't control anything. If you control the bootloader, that's it, only the kernel need to be verified. And you can couple the bootloader and the kernel with a suitable use of key-pairs.

Comment: thanks, tempering kernel is another issue, and an integrity check may help on it(what verified u-boot would do). I know of TPM or HAB from NXP etc, which is suggestion of implementing a secure, secure-boot scenario. Can you explain a little more on "bootloader and the kernel with a suitable use of key-pairs"